# randomize observations by groups (blocks)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with `I` obsevations, and each observation belongs to one of `g` categories.

```
set.seed(9782)
I <- 500
g <- 10
library(dplyr)

anon_id <- function(n = 1, length = 12) {
  randomString <- c(1:n)
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                    length, replace = TRUE),
                             collapse = "")
  }
  return(randomString)
}

df <- data.frame(id = anon_id(n = I, length = 16),
                 group = sample(1:g, I, T))
```

I want to randomly assign each observation to one of `J` "urns", given some vector of probabilities `p`. That is the probability of being assign to urn J=1 is p[1]. The added complexity is that I want to do this block by block.

If I ignore the blocks, I can do this easily:

```
J <- 3
p <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.25)
df1 <- df %>% mutate(urn = sample(x = c(1:J), size = I, replace = T, prob = p))
```

I thought about this method to do it by "block"

```
# Block randomization
randomize_block <- function(g) {
  df1 <- df %>% filter(group==g) 
  size <- nrow(df1)
  df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(urn = sample(x = c(1:J), 
                                     size = size, 
                                     replace = T, 
                                     prob = p))
  return(df1)
                        
}

df2 <- lapply(1:g, randomize_block)
df2 <- data.table::rbindlist(df2)
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you just group by group before you mutate?

Comment: @bramtayl I thought about that, but I'm not sure how I would pass the `size` to the sample function in that case. Each group can have a different number of observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is better, but here is a base R technique with data.frame df, that has group name "group" as well as urn assignments `1:J` with assignment probabilities in vector p of length J.

```
# get urn assignment
urnAssignment  <- lapply(unique(df$group), 
                    function(i) sample(1:J, nrow(df[group==i,]), replace =T, prob=p))

# get a list that collects position of observations
obsOrder  <- lapply(unique(df$group), 
                    function(i) which(df$group == i))

df$urnAssignment <- unlist(urnAssignment)[unlist(obsOrder)]
```

Answer (score 3):

[randomizr::block_ra](https://declaredesign.org/r/randomizr/reference/block_ra.html) does exactly what you want.

```
library(randomizr)
library(janitor) #just for the tabyl function

block_rand <-  as.tibble(randomizr::block_ra(blocks = df$group, conditions = c("urn_1","urn_2","urn_3")))

df2 <- as.tibble(bind_cols(df, block_rand))

df2 %>% janitor::tabyl(group, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick using `dplyr`:

```
randomize <- function(data, groups=2, block_id = NULL, p=NULL, seed=9782) {
  if(is.null(p)) p <- rep(1/groups, groups) 
  if(is.null(block_id)){
    df1 <- data %>% 
      mutate(Treatment = sample(x = c(1:groups), 
                                size = n(), 
                                replace = T, 
                                prob = p))
    return(df1)
  }else{
    df1 <- data %>% group_by_(block_id) %>% 
      mutate(Treatment = sample(x = c(1:groups), 
                                size = n(), 
                                replace = T, 
                                prob = p))
  }
}    

df1 <- randomize(data = df, groups = J, block_id = "group", p = p, seed = 9782)
```