# randomize observations by groups (blocks) without replacement

Tags: r, dplyr

This is a [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36600511/randomize-observations-by-groups-blocks). The answers in the previous question are doing the random sampling with replacement. How can I change the code so that I assign each observation to on of `J` "urn" without putting the observation back in the 'lottery'?

This is the code I have right now:

```
set.seed(9782)
I <- 500
g <- 10
library(dplyr)

anon_id <- function(n = 1, lenght = 12) {
  randomString <- c(1:n)
  for (i in 1:n)
  {
    randomString[i] <- paste(sample(c(0:9, letters, LETTERS),
                                    lenght, replace = TRUE),
                             collapse = "")
  }
  return(randomString)
}

df <- data.frame(id = anon_id(n = I, lenght = 16),
                 group = sample(1:g, I, T))

J <- 3
p <- c(0.25, 0.5, 0.25)

randomize <- function(data, urns=2, block_id = NULL, p=NULL, seed=9782) {
  if(is.null(p)) p <- rep(1/urns, urns) 
  if(is.null(block_id)){
    df1 <- data %>% 
      mutate(Treatment = sample(x = c(1:urns), 
                                size = n(), 
                                replace = T, 
                                prob = p))
    return(df1)
  }else{
    df1 <- data %>% group_by_(block_id) %>% 
      mutate(Treatment = sample(x = c(1:urns), 
                                size = n(), 
                                replace = T, 
                                prob = p))
  }
}    

df1 <- randomize(data = df, urns = J, block_id = "group", p = p, seed = 9782)
```

If I change `replace = T` to `replace = F` I get the following error:

> Error: cannot take a sample larger than the population when 'replace = FALSE'

---

Clarification of my objective:

Suppose that I have 10 classrooms (or villages, or something like that). To keep it simple, suppose each classroom has 20 students (in reality they will have N_j). Classroom per classroom, I want to assign each student to one of J groups, for example `J=3`. P says the fraction that will be assigned to each group. For example 25% to group 1 40% to group 2 and 35% to group 3.

Comment: in the final call `groups = J = 3` but you created `df` with `g=10` groups?

Comment: `df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(sample_size = n())` will show you how many samples you are asking for per group in the mutate

Comment: @jaimedash i was using the word groups to refer to two different things. I updated the code to fix that. I have J=3 `urns` and I want to do the random assignment by `group`

Comment: Are you looking to sprinkle in some `NA`'s: `sample(c(1:urns, rep(NA, n() - urns)))`? I don't understand how else you want to assign 3 values to e.g. 10 slots without replacement.

Comment: @eddi I just added a clarification. Hopefully it makes my objective clear.

Comment: `sample(rep(seq_along(J), p*I))` with special handling if you have `p*I` not being integer-valued.

Comment: @Frank could you please elaborate?

Comment: Suppose I have N = 20 people and I want them split/partitioned/assigned into groups of sizes p = c(.25,.5,.25). In that case, I need to create an assignment vector with .25*20 = 5 entries for the first group, 10 for the second, 5 for the third, like `a0 = rep(seq_along(p), N*p)`. Now, I'll make these assignments random by taking a permutation: `a = sample(a0)`

Comment: @Frank thanks a lot!

Comment: @Frank, please let me know if you have some advise about how to improve the implementation of your solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is based on @Frank's comment. I created one function that does the randomization for block `j` and another that calls that function for every block.

```
randomize_block <- function(data, block=NULL, block_name=NULL, urns, p, seed=9782) {
  set.seed(seed)
  if(!is.null(block)) {
    condition <- paste0(block_name,"==",block)
    df <- data %>% filter_(condition)
  } else df <- data
  if(is.null(p)) p <- rep(1/urns, urns) 
  N <- nrow(df)
  Np <- round(N*p,0)
  if(sum(Np)!=N) Np[1] <- N - sum(Np[2:length(Np)])
  Urns = rep(seq_along(p), Np)
  Urns = sample(Urns)
  df$urn <- Urns
  return(df)
}   

randomize <- function(data, block_name=NULL, urns, p, seed=9782) {
  if(is.null(p)) p <- rep(1/urns, urns)
  if(!is.null(block_name)){
    blocks <- unique(data[,block_name])
    df <- lapply(blocks, randomize_block, 
                 data = data, 
                 block_name=block_name, 
                 urns = urns, 
                 p = p, 
                 seed=seed)
    return(data.table::rbindlist(df))
  }else {
    df <- randomize_block(data = data,  
                          urns = urns, p = p, 
                          seed=seed)
  }
}

test <- randomize(data = df, block_name = "group", 
                  urns = 3, p = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.25), 
                  seed=4222016)
```

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to use `dplyr` to do this, alternative solutions implementing that are more than welcome!

Comment: Looks good. I would probably do it as `random_partition = function(p, N){Np <- round(N*p); Np[1L] <- N - sum(Np[-1L]); sample(rep(seq_along(p), Np))}; setDT(df)[, urn := random_partition(p, .N), by=group]`

Answer (score 1):

[My answer to your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60232507/11234387) is without replacement, as can be seen below:

```
block_rand <-  as.tibble(randomizr::block_ra(blocks = df$group, conditions = c("urn_1","urn_2","urn_3")))

df2 <- as.tibble(bind_cols(df, block_rand))

df2 %>% janitor::tabyl(group, value) 

df2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>%
  str()
```